# Character stuck on a tile unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have no idea what to say, but I have this image which shows how the character is stuck, the character gets stuck when I try to jump couple times, character is not falling.

if I jump 1 more time, the character jumps and drops to the ground [image]

Here is movement [code](https://controlc.com/1e842bc5) (didn't want to paste it here cuz it is kind of big)

oh and btw this is 2.5d game, 2d in a 3d engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are stuck on a subpixel?

- Check the colliders: Window->Analysis->Physics Debugger.
- Check the x-coordinates of the blocks in each "tower".
- Change from boxcollider to spherecollider (so you slip off of small edges?)

What about the "GroundCheck Transform"? I don't see why it's a separate transform, is it a child of the player?

Comment: i changed it into capsule collider and it worked thanks